# Figure-of-merit with Transiesta/TBtrans

Tags: software-recommendations, one-topic-per-answer, siesta, electronic-transport

Would it be possible to calculate the figure-of-merit:
$$ZT =\frac{S^2\sigma}{\kappa}T,\tag{1}$$
with Transiesta and TBTrans?

If not, which other programs can be used? I've only read about Gollum.

Comment: Do you mean you want to calculate each component, or you literally want something to compute ZT?

Comment: It would be ok both cases. I know that software that compute 'automatically' ZT do not include the phonon contribution to the thermal conductance. This is why I'm asking about TBTrans that I know has a phonon transport counterpart.

Comment: BoltzTrap2 is popular for the electronic components (S, \sigma, T, \kappa_el), but you'd have to think about how to model the transport relaxation time. AlmaBTE or ShengBTE would give you the lattice thermal conductivity (\kappa_latt).

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but can you let us know if Phil's comment was helpful, or if you've got an answer from elsewhere over the last few months? Are you still actively in need of an answer to this particular question? Please update us!